# Drop down choosing whether Single or Double pay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I hope someone will help me with this, here's the problem. All I want is when choose single in the drop down, I want the numbers in that textbox to be multiply by 1 and whether I choose double in the drop down it will only multiply by 2. Thank you in advance for the help. :)

[image]

Also here's my code, I think we can use onchange in here. But I don't know how? Thank you again for the help.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
Number:
<input type="text" id="fnum"/>
<br/><br/>
Type:
<select>
<option>Choose</option>
<option value="Single">Single</option>
<option value="Double">Double</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
Result:
<input type="text" id="result" readonly/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your question so that we can understand what you exactly want?

Comment: You need javascript for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go ahead and try this.
The variable value will contain the value that you have in your select (dropdown)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-/SIrNqv8h6QGKDuNoLGA4iret+kyesCkHGzVUUV0shc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
Number:
<input type="text" id="fnum"/>
<br/><br/>
Type:
<select>
<option>Choose</option>
<option value="Single">Single</option>
<option value="Double">Double</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
Result:
<input type="text" id="result" readonly/>
</form>
<script>
$('document').ready(function(){
$('select').change(function(){
    var value = $('select').val();
    var fnum = $('#fnum').val();
    if(value == 'Single'){
       var result = fnum*1;
       $("#result").val(result);
    }
    else if(value == 'Double'){
       var result = fnum*2;
       $("#result").val(result);
    }
})
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is ok when I use this link when I don't have a jquery file?
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I think your answer or the logic of it is correct, but it will not showing anything in the result textbox? :(

Comment: I have made an edit to your post too. Please copy your html and this javascript

Comment: I've tried it already, but it will not showing anything in the result. :(

Comment: Are you using jQuery? Have you included the library? Please check console, if jQuery is not included, it will trough an error $ is not defined

Comment: yes! It is ok to use this?
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I have made an edit to the answer, try the whole code.

Comment: It is working at my end, I have put a number in the text box and then I change the value in dropdown and I get the multiplied result.

Comment: Just paste whatever you see in the answer.